# How to check if column exists in sqlite in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have an application which uses sqlite database. I updated the application and needed to update my database on application launch.

For this I need to check if some column exists in a table. I am not sure how to do it...

I saw PRAGMA table_info(table-name); will return column names but that result is in a table and I am not sure how to read it in Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) returns its data like a normal query, i.e., as if there were a query `SELECT cid, name, type, notnull, dflt_value, pk FROM ...`:

```cpp
query.exec("PRAGMA table_info(MyLittleTable)");
while (query.next()) {
    print("column name: ", query.value(1));
}
```

Comment: does executing this command alter the database? Why I ask is that, when I run this 'PRAGMA table_info(MyLittleTable)' in a third party sqlite browser, it asks to write changes to database/revert changes...

Comment: This statement does not modify the database. This looks like a bug in that third party browser.